# Restyling the Youtube DOM elements for a improved experience

Tags: html, css, polymer, dom-manipulation, html-rendering

Every Youtube video has a column div which has 2 children primary and secondary:

[image: primary div]

[image: secondary div]

primary div has a child 'ytd-comments' element which contains all comments and I want to put it in the secondary div but whenever I cut paste the 'ytd-comments' element in the secondary div all the comments ids in the 'ytd-comments' div goes missing, see below this content div is empty.

[image: ytd-comments element]

Comment: Its Better to provide some code which can demonstrate what have you done so far.

Comment: Hi, code (or HTML in this situation) is text, please do not put pictures of text in questions (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing *Stylus* – an extension for Chrome, Firefox and Opera that injects CSS into pages, and then use the following CSS code:

```
#columns #secondary {
    display: none;
}

#columns #primary {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 24px;
}


#columns #primary > div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}


#columns #primary > div > * {
    width: var(--ytd-watch-flexy-player-width);
}

#columns #primary > div > ytd-comments {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: calc(100% + 24px);
    max-width: 45vw;
}
```

[edit]

Wow, I really enjoyed this new look. Here is a style if you want to keep the `#secondary` *Up Next* column:

```
#columns #primary {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

#columns #primary > div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}


#columns #primary > div > * {
    width: var(--ytd-watch-flexy-player-width);
}

#columns #primary > div > ytd-comments {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: calc(100% + 24px);
    max-width: calc(100vw - var(--ytd-watch-flexy-player-width) - (3 * 24px) - 400px);
}

#columns #secondary {
    width: 400px; /* 400px in the max-width above */
}
```